# Is Session "X" user independent or defines different session of the same user?

Tags: c#, asp.net

in ASP.NET, in this code, what is X defining, if we already get the session name from textbox?
do I have to create a guid for each user to change this X? Or does it just change if I need multiple sessions from the same browser? I need clarification. thanks.

```
Session["X"] = TextBox1.Text;
```

Comment: You're just giving the session an X variable and putting text from the textbox in it. It's unique for each session, so you don't have to use guids etc, one user having this code run will not affect the "X" session variable of another user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're just giving the session an X variable and putting text from the textbox in it. It's unique for each session, so you don't have to use guids etc, one user having this code run will not affect the "X" session variable of another user.

Comment: Why the downvote, he specifically asked for the comment to be reposted, and it was my own comment...